# removeAllOptions() can onlybe used with select, ol and ul elements. Attempt to use: Object this an alert that is showing on keyup function on FIREFOX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

`removeAllOptions()` can only be used with `select`, `ol` and `ul` elements. Attempt to use: Object is an alert that is showing only on FIREFOX it calling keyup within the text box.

Comment: that how can we remove this alert.

Answer (score 1):

Per:
http://ajaxcfc.riaforge.org/forums/messages.cfm?threadid=31E6814A-A676-33A8-845BDF46E0512126, try the following if you are using jQuery with DWR and getting reported error/alert:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict()</script>
```